# Thymeleaf static images not being found

Tags: java, css, spring, thymeleaf

I've just added a bootstrap template to the app I'm working on and have been the process of making it, and Thymeleaf like each other.

I'm unable to serve up the images when I head off to different pages - I've tried both contextual using the `th:src="@{/img/name.png}"` notation and the server `th:src="@{~/img/name.png}"` that I've read through in the docs.

When run the application is accessed via :`http://localhost:8080/`, there is no 'app name' so to speak which may be the issue as a few of the examples I read through looked to be expected `http://localhost:8080/myApp/myPage.html` instead.

On this page: `http://localhost:8080/home` or any other root level page the images are displayed.

On one of these pages I redirect the user to  `@RequestMapping("/{userid}/users")` which resolves to `http://localhost:8080/1/games` - it's on this page I encounter the errors.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

With the images being: `http://localhost:8080/1/img/icons/double-arrow.png`
where '1' is the userId that was passed in to the controller.

My css / img files are in `resources/static/css` and `resources/static/img`. I've checked and confirmed that they exist.

I'm using fragments for the header and footer, the css and js files don't have a problem.

Any suggestions on how to resolve would be great, thanks!

edited to add some clarity:

This is part of the html page,

```
 <a href="games.html" th:href="@{/{userid}/users}"/></a>
```

the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/{userid}/users")
    public String userGames(@PathVariable final Long userid, Model model){

...get, other methods, etc
        return "users";
```

The '1' that can be seen in the url above is the userid that issuing passed in.

Comment: Your image url contains 'src' yet your static image path does not?

Comment: Just to verify have you added `SecurityConfiguration`?

Comment: @soorapadman - no security config in place, no.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your image url is wrong. Shouldn't it be `th:src="@{/img/name.png}"` since you said you put it in folder `resources/static/img`?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part.  

Files are in resources/static/img and all references to them are th:src="@{/img/img.png}"

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `{/Users/UserId}`? Maybe you meant `/users/{userid}`? I am wondering because there 
 is no `users` part in your url `http://localhost:8080/1/img/icons/double-arrow.png`. Also, the url `http://localhost:8080/1/img/icons/double-arrow.png` would look in `resources/static/1/img/icons/` and I bet that is not what you want. I think you should remove the 1.

Comment: I've edited the question.  The '1' is the userid that's being passed in from the html link

Comment: Ok, but my point still is why would you put the userid in the url to the image? The image is not user specific, is it? If you put your images in a static content folder the link to the image can not be dynamic.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here.  I 'haven't' put it in the url to the image, In the html, on that page, it's /img/img.png - the '1' is being passed in.  the pics 'should' be taken from the root as expected. and the 1 could just as easily be any other nested page.  products/product1/produtdetails or something like that.